# C# Smooth Rainbow Fading issue

Tags: c#

So I am trying to make this text label that has a really smooth rainbow fade by just added different values to a RGB and setting the label to those values, but I cant find a way to stop the starting value which starts the whole process!
I know this code is messy and there's unneeded stuff like that random number thingy. But it throws the error "System.ArgumentException: 'Value of '256' is not valid for 'red'. 'red' should be greater than or equal to 0 and less than or equal to 255.'"

```
    int R = 0;
    int G = 0;
    int B = 0;

    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random r = new Random();

        int A = r.Next(255, 255);

        R += 1;
        if (R > 250)
        {
            G += 1;
            R -= 1;
        }

        if (G > 250)
        {
            B += 1;
            G -= 1;
        }

        if (B > 250)
        {
            R += 1;
            B -= 1;
        }

        lblMarquee.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(A, R, G, B);
    }
```

Comment: use modulo arithmetic to clamp down on the values

Comment: I know this is a lot to ask but I am pretty new to all of this, and don't understand a thing about 'modulo arithmetic' if you could give more clarification or even make me a solution to this problem that would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: once B gets to 251, R starts counting up again..... forever.

Comment: also, usually, moving through the RGB color space is not  as pleasing as moving through the HSL color space.

Comment: First of all, we can not understand what exactly you want, And also according to the error message you got, the value cannot be greater than 256, it should be between 0..255, Why you asking for this!?!?!

Comment: Yes that's pretty much what im doing here, but the problem is right here

the R += 1; is infinitly counting up with no stop on the timer making it impossible to use the R -= 1; function.

Comment: so work out a better way of doing it :)

Comment: Mohammad Read the full post and you will see what im trying to do...

Comment: Keith Im here for a answer and help. Not for people to say "do it yourself"

Comment: we have told you why it is wrong, there are many many ways to solve this problem and it would be offtopic to try and answer it.

Comment: [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Keith what you said to do is literally what I am doing but that is wrong, you are not telling me how to fix this problem you are basically saying "oh I don't know, figure it out" So please help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of problems with your code here, so I thought I'd just focus on that. As for your rainbow colour scheme, I'm not sure even if you are on the right track. However assuming you are this should help you out:

```
// never recreate the random class in your method
// always just create one
private static readonly Random _rand = new Random();

// your variables, make them byte as that's what we are dealing with
private static byte _r = 0;
private static byte _g = 0;
private static byte _b = 0;
private static byte _a = 0;

private static SomeMethod()
{

    // make your life easier with some helper methods
    void Inc(ref byte val)
      => val = (byte)(val>=255 ? 0: val++);
    
    void Dec(ref byte val)
       => val = (byte)(val<=0 ? 255: val--);
    
    // not sure why you want this
    _a = (byte)_rand.Next(255);
    
    _r += 1;
    
    // I have no idea what your logic is here, but it looks neater
    // and won't overflow, which is your problem
    // however I seriously doubt this will give you a rainbow
    if (_r > 250)
    {
       Inc(ref _g);
       Dec(ref _r);
    }
    
    if (_g > 250)
    {
       Inc(ref _b);
       Dec(ref _g);
    }
    
    if (_b > 250)
    {
       Inc(ref _r);
       Dec(ref _b);
    } 
    
    lblMarquee.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(_a, _r, _g, _b);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int R = 0;
    int G = 0;
    int B = 0;
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        

        Random r = new Random();

        int A = r.Next(255, 255);

        R += 1;
        if (R >= 250)
        {
            G += 1;
            R -= 1;
        }

        if (G >= 250)
        {
            B += 1;
            G -= 1;
        }

        if (B >= 250)
        {

            timer2.Interval = 10;
            timer2.Start();
            timer1.Stop();

            
        }
        label1.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(A, R, G, B);
    }

    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random r = new Random();

        int A = r.Next(255, 255);
        R -= 1;

        if (R <= 5)
        {
            G -= 1;
            R += 1;
        }
        if (G <= 5)
        {
            B -= 1;
            G += 1;
        }
        if (B <= 5)
        {
            R = 0;
            G = 0;
            B = 0;
            
            timer1.Start();
            timer2.Stop();
            
        }
        label1.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(A, R, G, B);
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).